# Listing and excluding System Databases in a Combo Box using SMO

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have read a post by Chris Diver and found the code to be useful. However I wish to exclude System Databases. The code is:

```
Dim server As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("localhost")
 For Each db As Database In server.Databases
   Console.WriteLine(db.Name)
 Next
```

Source: [Get list of databases from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server)

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look properties listed in the MSDN doco and see if you can guess which one will help you out; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the database. Don't add if its system db. Here is a piece of code for this

```
Dim value As Boolean

For Each db As Database In server.Databases
   value = db .IsSystemObject
   if NOT value  Then
       Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(db.Name)
    End If
Next
```