# Detecting available db in the SQL Server through vb.net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I have a query I am creating a Window App in vb.net (4.0) in which I have to use multiple databases although all databases are same with same db structure & stored procedures,just names are different. In the very starting of application, I need to give a option to the user that these are available db & user will select which one to connect & use.

**So is it possible to detect how many db are available in the SQL Server through vb.net & how can achieve this (to provide options to the user)** ?
What would be the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of databases from Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dependso n permissions.

Basically you can always conect to the server and ask the server. All metadaa is available in the system management database and you can submit sql there to ask for waht databases exist.

[Get list of databases from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

The sql server knows how many databases are installed, you can just query it.  Your login needs to have permission to make the query, so you probably will want to use different connection strings for this query vs others.

Also, given the right permissions you can discover not only if the database exist, but whether it is structually acceptable

Answer (score 0):

sure, you just have to call any procedure on the server that can list the DB's for you. Try:

```
EXEC sp_databases
EXEC sp_helpdb
```

there is also an  Un-Documented Procedure

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'PRINT ''?'''
```