# List all the available databases running on particular instance of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I know how to get all the instances of SQL Servers using `SqlDataSourceEnumerator`class. But how can I get list of databases running on a particular instance ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of all database from sql server in a combobox using c#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703193/how-to-get-list-of-all-database-from-sql-server-in-a-combobox-using-c-net)

Comment: I don't really think this is a duplicate, merely because the duplicate doesn't address how to restrict the list to *available* databases (I'm making an assumption about what the OP means).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using anything >= SQL Server ***2005***, use `sys.databases`, from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx):

```
SELECT name, user_access_desc, is_read_only, state_desc, recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases;
```

For < ***2005***:

```
SELECT name
FROM master..sysdatabases
```

You can also execute the stored procedue `sp_databases` and capture the result:

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

See also this answer: [How to get list of all database from sql server in a combobox using c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703193/how-to-get-list-of-all-database-from-sql-server-in-a-combobox-using-c-net)

Answer (score 2):

I would use

```
select name, state_desc from sys.databases
```

but this would return all databases with their statuses.