# Extract information from SQL Server Management Studio, C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

My question is how to get the information from the database (I'm using SQL Server Managements Studio) so I can use it in my .NET Core Application? I can already record, but how to get the information back to the application?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How do you record it?

Comment: Your .NET app will need to execute a `SELECT` query to retrieve data. This can be done in .NET Core using `SqlConection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` objects in the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` namespace. See the [SqlCommand doocumenttion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand) for example code.

Comment: hi @Stela,, should I read this as a question about the Database Server or the Database Management Studio ? Dan is right, the way to go for data in .NET is Data.SqlClient. I'd like to add Entity Framework as a candidate, too.. If you'd like to inquire available databases on a Database Server, you can use the examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703193/how-to-get-list-of-all-database-from-sql-server-in-a-combobox-using-c-net

Answer (score 0):

You can use entity framework core and linqQ query to retrieve data from database in .net core.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

public class DataRepo
{
  MatterDataContext _database = new MatterDataContext();
  public IEnumerable<Matter> GetMatters(int matterId)
  {
    IEnumerable<Matter> matters = _database.Matters.Where(m => m.MatterId== matterId);

    return matters;
  }        
}
```

_database will be your object of data context class. Matters is entity class. Name of database table and entity class name should be same (i.e, Matters). Matters is table from DB as well as entity class name.

```
IEnumerable<Matter> matters = _database.Matters.Where(m => m.MatterId== matterId);
```

Above code line use entity framework core with the help of linqQ query to retrieve data from table where MatterId gets match with table's MatterId.