# Fetching all tables a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have made two drop down boxes. The first drop lists the available databases. When a user selects a database from the first drop down box, I would like to populate the 2nd drop down box with all tables in that that database.

Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

This is my code which I have tried

```
School Name:<select style="width: 140px" name="users" >
                    <option value="">Select school_name </option>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) {

?>
<option value='<?php echo $row->Database; ?>'><?php echo $row->Database; ?>   </option>
    <?php }?>

</select><br/>
Class:<select style="width: 140px" name="users" >
                    <option value="">Select school_name </option>

    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $db_list = mysql_list_tables($link);                            
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) {

    ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $row->Tables; ?>'><?php   echo $row->Tables; ?></option>
              <?php }?>

</select>

<?php
}
?>
```

Now I want to get all the tables in second drop down based on first drop down box.

Comment: can anyone provide me the code using mysql in php

Comment: show the code that you have tried

Comment: @pinkiupadhyay did u got my answer, if anything unclear please ask me ?

Comment: @John Can u plz provide me the live url..If possible can do changes in my code...first drop down should be as it is,,,you can change the second drop down

Answer (score 1):

To get databse : [Get list of databases from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server)

To get tables in a database : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Use AJAX to change the tables based on database drop down box.

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO, you would just use the `SHOW TABLES` command:

```
$result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES");
```

To get a list of all databases, use the `SHOW DATABASES` command:

```
$result = $db->query( 'SHOW DATABASES' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

To fetch the DB lising:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA ;
```

To fetch tbe Table Listing:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DBName';
```

Answer (score 0):

***Just try with the following Sample :***

Create Two **PHP** files as follows,

**(1). index.php :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_tables(db_name){
$.post("fetch_data.php", { db_name: db_name },
function(data) {
$("#tables_list").html(data);
}
);
}
</script>
<table>
<tr><td><label>Select Your Database Name :</label></td><td><select name="database_list" onChange="get_tables(this.value);">
<option value="Wp-Sparks">Wp-Sparks</option>
<option value="Ja_Sparks">Ja_Sparks</option>
<option value="test">Test</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Select Your Database Tables :</label></td><td><select name="tables_list" id="tables_list"></select></td></tr>
</table>
```

**(2). fetch_data.php :**

```
<?php
$dbname =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['db_name']);
if (!mysql_connect('HOST_NAME', 'USER_NAME', 'PASSWORD')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"><?php echo $row[0];?></option>
<?php
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: It's one thing helping the OP use deprecated extensions, but your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection. `$_POST['db_name'];` is user input. User input that is concatenated to a query string without being escaped. Escape your user input first, please. Ideally, the OP should just use PDO or MySQLi. But that's their choice.

Comment: Not possible, it's working for me 100% sure,can i show a live demo url ?

Comment: @pinki Your question is "When a user selects a database from the first drop down box, I would like to populate the 2nd drop down box with all tables in that database." above one is the running example of your question.

Comment: If possible can do changes in my code...first drop down should be as it is,,,you can change the second drop down..

Comment: You need to give grant root access for your main database username and password after that only you can populate the tables as per the database, this should be done for live hostings. For localhost it wont need you just use the root username and password, because it has already root access for all database access. I think you got my point now. Where you struck with it.