# Count the total number of databases

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL server having a large number of databases. I want to count the number of databases. Is there any query to count?

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases 

OR

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.databases
```

Comment: i appreciate the shared love in the form of upvotes Shovan, but an accepted answer wouldn't hurt for yogi either ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
SELECT Count(*) as DatabaseCount FROM master..sysdatabases
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) as DatabaseCount FROM master.sys.databases
```

Answer (score 2):

try `select COUNT(*) from sysdatabases` or `select COUNT(*) from sys.databases`

edited from source: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic401516-463-1.aspx#bm816566

Answer (score 2):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.databases where database_id not in ( 1,2,3,4 ).. excluding system database

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(1) FROM sys.databases
```

this is what you can have for counting the number of database check [this](http://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/30652) link for more info

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know the count, check this-

```
select COUNT(*) from sys.databases
```

check `select * from sysdatabases` for 2000 and 2005 server