# Connecting to server vs connecting to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the difference between connecting to a server as opposed to connecting to a database?

The context of the question is that I'm in charge of developing a proof of concept where a user can select one of our servers, a database within that server, a table within that database, and a column within that table. I am using Visual C# and ASP.NET. I believe I can get the servers from the connection strings in the web.config, but I'm not quite sure how.

If it helps at all (I do like examples), you can assume SQL servers.

Comment: You don't connect to a database. You connect to a database server.

Comment: Can you show me how you connect to a database without connecting to a server?

Comment: @Oded No. I understand a database is on a server, so you have to connect to a server in order to get to a databases.

Comment: Are you talking about what's the different between connecting just to the server, or the database instance name? In the connection string: "data source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=DATABASENAME; user ID=....", or "data source=SERVERNAME\DATABASEINSTANCENAME; initial catalog=DATABASENAME; user ID=..."?

Comment: OK. So can you explain what you are asking here? It is really not clear and I think probably doesn't fall under the guidelines in the FAQ either.

Comment: Perhaps I could reword it like this: How do I list the databases on a server given a connection string? I've always connected to databases before, and to me this seems different.

Comment: You should probably edit your question to reflect what you're really asking.

Comment: @Oded, honestly - I think it's quite clear what he's asking - and I don't know why he has attracted all these down-votes.  From what I can tell, he wants to connect *without* connecting to an explicit database, but wants to connect to the server itself to, say, list databases that are available. :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice - That very first sentence will throw anyone off. That's a question all by itself.

Comment: The question is fine, and achievable. See my reply below.

Comment: @Oded, agreed - but further reading in to the question shows exactly what he is asking.  At least, it does to me.. YMMV :) ... and I agree wholeheartedly with your edit.

Comment: @Moo-Juice - Sure. But this deserves an edit to clarify the actual question.

Comment: @Moo-Juice , the first sentence before he edited it was "what's the difference with connecting to a server versus a database".

Comment: @MikeMarks, I know... I saw it in that state.  But further reading clarified it.  Anyway, this is irrelevant as Oded has correctly edited the question and it makes perfect sense now :)

Comment: I still think this question deserves -1 because he hasn't researched it on his own, and hasn't tried anything.

Comment: Oded: My apologies for any confusion. I forgot to add the part where if my question is nonsense to please help straighten me out. Moo-Juice and HardCode: Thank you.

Comment: Steve: I'm sorry, but my searching brought up a lot of information on connecting to databases which didn't help me out much for listing databases.

Comment: @ricksmt, did you just try searching google for `List databases on a server`

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain No. I was looking for a way to list databases given a connection string (from a web.config).

Comment: @ricksmt I am certain that a quick Google search will give you what you're asking for.  In fact, I searched for "asp.net list databases on server", and the 4th item in the search results: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/131413/List-all-databases-in-SQL-Server-in-ASPNet-Application-using-C/ - looks like what you need.

Comment: @Oded The reason for wording it the way I did was because I need to get the servers from the connection strings in my application's web.config--and I'm still not sure how to do that (but that's a different question; don't feel the need to answer that). That's why I was trying to distinguish between connecting to a server and a database, because I've never had to get server-level information before. I can understand why you edited the question the way you did, but it departs from the context I was coming from, and I'd like it to retain some of that for future searchers.

Comment: @dsum Sorry it's taking me so long to process all this. I didn't realize there would be such a fast response. Your question is quite helpful to me because I didn't know where the server name was in a connection string, and it implicitly reveals its location. And I'm now aware of database instances.

Comment: @MikeMarks I wouldn't have much trouble finding this answer either. The original question is harder (at least for me) to find answers to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get list of databases from Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your goal. Initially, you would connect to database `master` on the server and query the databases on that server.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

Then, you would initiate a new connection to the selected database and query that database's information schema, to get a list of tables.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Repeat for selecting a column.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'foo'
```

Comment: Hmm, never new about `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` I always used `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`.

Comment: He was wanting a way to list databases on a server given a connection string, which we're left to assume this is to be done within the .NET code, not T-SQL.

Comment: @MikeMarks Thanks for trying to make it easy for me. I'm okay with either actually. I haven't had much trouble translating SQL examples into .NET code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: In Management Studio, navigate to the database --> Views --> System Views. sys.tables and sys.columns are still there (in SQL Server 2008 R2) for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

(Answer to original question)

There is a hierarchy:

- **Server**: A piece of physical (or virtual) hardware that runs an OS and applications. You will address it via IP address or DNS name, in can host multiple Database Servers

  - **Database Server (aka Instance)**: A piece of software that runs that can host multiple Databases. when you use a connection string it is in the format "ServerName\InstanceName"

    - **Database**: A data structure that can host multiple Data Tables

      - **Data Table**: A data structure that can host multiple Columns and Rows

        - **Column**: The smallest division of information seperation, holds information about a specific topic
        - **Row**: Holds a single set of columns.

---

(Answer to updated question)

It is different per SQL provider, but using Microsleft SQL server you just connect to the server (don't provide a default instance in the connection string) and do the following:

```
select * from sys.databases
```

Once you have your database, connect to that database and do the following to get the tables

```
select * from sys.tables where type = 'U'
```

to get the columns you do

```
select * from sys.Columns
```

however to get the name of the table the column is in you need to match `Object_id` to `Object_id` on `sys.tables`

```
select t.name as TableName, c.Name as ColumnName  
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.Type = 'U'
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. Your answer helped me understand.

Answer (score 0):

If by server you mean database server, you would connect to the server to gain access to the database hosted on that server.