# Connect VB with SQL (Local + unknown database name)

Tags: sql, vb.net, odbc

Basically I want to know if it is possible to connect my VB app with SQL server on the same Computer (Local) and interrogate it for a list of database names.

I just want to know if that is possible.

sqlConn.ConnectionString = Data Source=local;Initial Catalog=unknownDatabase;User Id=knownUsername;Password=knownPassword;"

Fill DataBase Names to Drop Down

User Selects DB Name

Change Connection to now Known DatabaseName

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible.. You can create a connection to a local SQL instance the same way you'd create a connection to a remote one.

Then to get a list of the databases on the server, execute `"SELECT Name FROM master.sys.databases"`

Comment: When I try creating a connection to SQl, it asks for the database name tho..?

Comment: @UPGRAYEDD try setting initialcatalog=master, since you know master has to exist.

Comment: cool, Ill go ahead and code it tonight and try it at work in the morning, Thanks!