# VBA List databases on specific SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, t-sql

I'm trying to create a form with two listboxes. One is for SQL Server names; the other is for the databases on the server selected by the user.

In VBA I can get the server names by calling a stored procedure. However, I don't seem to be able to get a list of databases for a specific server.

Does anyone know how to write such a query?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a VBA question.

Comment: [Get list of databases from SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server) ?

Comment: Be careful of whatever you are doing here. Often the next step in this type of thing is to execute dynamic sql including the database name. Be careful if you do this to avoid sql injection.

Comment: This might be useful [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) if you want more.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a query against the server like:

```
SELECT
    name

FROM
    Sys.Databases
```