# SQL Server could not find stored procedure 'show'

Tags: sql, sql-server, show, management-studio-express

I can't use the most basic procedure, `show`, as it throws an error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'show'.

I used:

```
SHOW DATABASES
```

Please help me find answers to this issue.

Comment: That's a MySQL-specific command. It doesn't work with SQL Server.

Comment: Here is how to do that in SQL Server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server

Answer (score 12):

To list all Databases in SQL Server,

```
Select * from sys.databases
```

To exclude in-built DBs,

```
Select * from sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh local Cache which is under the Intellisense.

[image]