# SQL Server : Search for a string across all the databases and list all the databases, tables and corresponding columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am wondering if there is a way I can view all the databases and the corresponding tables where a specific string is present in SQL Server 2012.

I was able to search for a string in all the tables in a particular database by using a stored procedure below which I found online. But I would like to search it across all the databases.

```
  CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
@SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)

        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                    AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + 'WITH (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END    
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

And when I execute the below query, it lists all the tables along with the column names.

```
exec SearchAllTables "B2"
```

OUTPUT:

```
     ColumnName              ColumnValue
[dbo].[msm_temp].[molecule_nm]  B2
[dbo].[msm_temp1].[molecule_nm] B2
[dbo].[msm_temp2].[molecule_nm] B2
[dbo].[msm_temp3].[molecule_nm] B2
[dbo].[msm_temp4].[molecule_nm] B2
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server) for ways to enumerate all the databases on your server. From there it should be fairly easy to modify your query.

Comment: Are you trying to find all references to a specific column?

Comment: @Sparrow Yes all references where the string occurs is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this stored procedure with value for search like this :

```
exec SearchAllDatabases @SearchTerm = '%B2%'
```

This can help you to search everywhere but if you have too much data in your databases this will take time to execute.

Stored procedure :

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchAllDatabases
  @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

IF @SearchTerm IS NULL OR @SearchTerm NOT LIKE N'%[^%^_]%'
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR(N'Please enter a valid search term.', 11, 1);
RETURN;
  END

  CREATE TABLE #results
  (
    [database]   SYSNAME,
    [schema]     SYSNAME,
    [table]      SYSNAME,
    [column]     SYSNAME,
    ExampleValue NVARCHAR(1000)
  );

  DECLARE
    @DatabaseCommands  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', 
    @ColumnCommands NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

  SELECT @DatabaseCommands = @DatabaseCommands + N'
    EXEC ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.sp_executesql
        @ColumnCommands, N''@SearchTerm NVARCHAR(MAX)'', @SearchTerm;'
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id  > 4  -- non-system databases
      AND[state]      = 0-- online
      AND user_access  = 0; -- multi-user

    SET @ColumnCommands = N'DECLARE @q NCHAR(1),
          @SearchCommands NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @q = NCHAR(39),
  @SearchCommands = N''DECLARE @VSearchTerm VARCHAR(255) = @SearchTerm;'';

    SELECT @SearchCommands = @SearchCommands + CHAR(10) + N''

      SELECT TOP(1)
        [db]     = DB_NAME(),
        [schema] = N'' + @q + s.name + @q + '', 
        [table]  = N'' + @q + t.name + @q + '',
        [column] = N'' + @q + c.name + @q + '',
        ExampleValue = LEFT('' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + '', 1000)
      FROM '' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ''
      WHERE '' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + N'' LIKE @'' + CASE
        WHEN c.system_type_id IN(35, 167, 175) THEN ''V'' 
        ELSE '''' END + ''SearchTerm;'' 

    FROM sys.schemas AS s
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    WHERE c.system_type_id IN (35, 99, 167, 175, 231, 239)
      AND c.max_length >= LEN(@SearchTerm);

PRINT @SearchCommands;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SearchCommands,
  N''@SearchTerm NVARCHAR(255)'', @SearchTerm;';

  INSERT #Results
  (
    [database],
    [schema],
    [table],
    [column],
    ExampleValue
  )
  EXEC[master].sys.sp_executesql @DatabaseCommands,
   N'@ColumnCommands NVARCHAR(MAX), @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(255)', 
    @ColumnCommands, @SearchTerm;

  SELECT[Searched for] = @SearchTerm;

  SELECT[database],[schema],[table],[column],ExampleValue
FROM #Results 
    ORDER BY[database],[schema],[table],[column];
END
GO
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This query works okay but takes really long time. Is there any optimized solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure bro. But I try to optimize this. Because I need this too for searching in my databases. If this works for you and you like accept it.

Comment: Also this script throws this error:  SQL Server Database Error: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of left function.

Comment: I'm looking forward for someone help us upgrade this or a better query. But for now this one was best query for me that I've found.

Comment: The query is not working in my case. It runs without errors but returns a blank result. Do I need to run the script and create the stored procedure inside a specific database?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, You should create sp in a database and run inside same database. but it shows data in all databases in your server.