# how can I connect to a specific mysql and extract data

Tags: mysql

I have a server which has many mysql built .

I first do

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

It gives me what are the connections and I find one of them which is interesting for me. I want to know how I can have access to it and extract all the information in there

```
--------------+-----------+---------------+
| Id      | User      | Host                              | db        | Command | Time | State | Inf                                                                              o             | Rows_sent | Rows_examined |
+---------+-----------+-----------------------------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+----                                                                              --------------+-----------+---------------+
| 3037051 | TTUP | user.server:58257 | TTUP | Sleep   |    5 |       | NUL
```

The name of the database is TTUP

Many thanks

Comment: The host there is the *client*, not a server.

Comment: What do you mean by "many mysql built"?

Comment: You get access to it by using a terminal program like `ssh`.

Comment: @Barmar mean many data bases

Comment: You can use the command `use TTUP;` to use that database.

Comment: @Barmar can you please give me an example ? It is on a server and I want to know what is in there and how to extract the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `use` command to access a specific database:

```
mysql> use TTUP
```

Then you can list the tables in the database:

```
mysql> show tables;
```

Comment: I first go to the main mysql ` mysql -u root -p` then I use `use` and then `show tables`  . can I see specific tables, add tables or extract info from it to my desktop ?

Comment: This is a database, you write SQL queries to extract data from it.

Comment: Like `SELECT * FROM tablename;`

Comment: can you direct me to some example or something ? please . do you also have expernce with catalyst perl ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a tutorial on how to use MySQL. I don't have any recommendations.

Comment: Did you understand "I don't have any recommendations"?

Answer (score 0):

use php mysqli or PDO to make a connection to database. Example to mysqli:

```
<?php $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "DB-username", "Password", "TTUP"); mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,'utf8');

$sql=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM yourTabelName");
while($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()){$array[]=$row;}
?>
<pre><?php print_r($array);?></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks I did that but nothing happend . I use Cygwin64 to connect to a server with all those databases. I don't know what is in those databases and I want to get an idea about them

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server

Comment: actually i still could not get info. probably i dont know how to connect to the database