# Get the list of attached databases on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server I can issue following query

```
CREATE DATABASE.... FOR ATTACH;
```

which will allow a `foreign` database access on one connection.

Is there a query that will return all such attached database names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list of databases from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147659/get-list-of-databases-from-sql-server)

Comment: If you mean "can I somehow distinguish between databases that were attached from somewhere else, and databases that were created on the instance itself", then no. To the engine there is no difference. Furthermore, your description of what `FOR ATTACH` does is misleading at best -- it doesn't give access "on one connection", it simply makes the database available to the instance as a whole. It's not a temporary or transient thing; after this statement the database files are managed by the instance and will remain so until removed or detached.

Comment: @Filburt, IIUC, this will return the list of databases on the current server, whether I connect to them or not. I explicitly stated that I need a list of `attached` DBs

Comment: @JeroenMostert, than you for explanation. I understand in theory what is an `attached DB` is, but you put it out nicely. Now in terms of distinguishing - there is no way to query the server? Is there a way to detach the database after I'm done? Because if there is - server should somehow keep track of the attached DBs. OTOH, it might be something internal...

Comment: You can detach databases with [`sp_detach_db`](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-db-transact-sql). Do read the usage notes for that (like having to have exclusive access). If you want to get technical, the server does indeed keep track of attached databases -- *all* databases are attached. The only difference between `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE .. FOR ATTACH` is that the former creates new files to attach, while the second one uses existing files. You can attach and detach databases as you please, regardless of where their origin.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, ok, so IIUC, every database on MS SQL Server is attached on connection or when I do `use <db_name>`. Thank you - now it becomes more clear.

Comment: No. Connecting to a DB has nothing to do with attaching the files. The files are *permanently* attached, and the database server reads them at server startup (LocalDB instances do work slightly differently, and there is an `AttachDBFileName` in connection strings which is best avoided, but that's the main idea). `USE` simply switches the context of the connection to an already attached and initialized database. Even shutting down the server does not detach the database, it just releases the open file handles and locks. The DB remains attached and will be opened again on next startup.